# serializing C# objects with JavaScriptSerializer produces invalid bytes in UTF8 string

Tags: c#, json, r, utf-8, javascriptserializer

I am serializing a C# object with the following code:

```
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(rawFile);
            Console.WriteLine(serializedResult);
            return;
```

Tried serialization with Target Frameworks from 4.5 up to 4.6.1.

Then I am trying deserialize it into R:

```
     > x <-  read_json("C:\\dump.txt")
     Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
     lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string.
             ": "Sample pickup:\nVolume [æl]         :     1.00\nFlow [æl
                        (right here) ------^
```

I am guessing that these are a micro liter. How to best handle these special characters?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to use Newtonsoft JSON converter?

Comment: How do you move your UTF-8 string from C# to R? If you output it to console, well... it can be broken.
(also C# `String`s are not UTF-8, so if you want to get UTF-8 bytes you need to utilize methods from, if my memory is ok, `Encoding` class).

Comment: So _imho_ _probably_ it's not serializer that produces wrong UTF-8 bits in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial hint was from Sergey "If you output it to console, well... it can be broken."

Using File.WriteAllText solves the problem:

```
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(rawFile);
            // byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(serializedResult);
            // string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            File.WriteAllText("dump2.txt", serializedResult);
```